# How to flush all cmd messages to a txt file?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, cmd

I am executing a `.bat` file from `cmd` . But for some reason, at some point there are some error messages on cmd screen, and the `cmd` window self exits so that I don't have enough time to read those error messages. So I tried to flush everything to a `.txt` file like this

```
cd "C:\Users\myPath\"
@echo off
test.txt (
java  -cp ".;C:\Users\myPath\JARs\xxx.jar;C:\Users\myPath\JARs\yyy.jar;" myJavaClassFile
)
```

I also tried this

```
test.bat > testlog.txt 2> testerrors.txt
```

But none of the above methods show all error messages that show up on the `cmd` screen before it closes

Comment: There is no way to redirect output that an application has intentionally sent directly to the console rather than to standard output or standard error.  That might be what is happening in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick a Pause command at the end of the batch file.

Comment: Or simply execute the batch file manually from a command window prompt.